# Magento 2.3.0 stucks at 50%

Tags: installation, magento2.3.0

I have installed **Magento 2.3.0** in my local machine, but it stuck at 50% there is no error on Magento **console.log** but I could see an error in browser console.

Error Snapshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/OidJb3M0

> http://localhost/zmagento/setup/index.php/session/prolong its
>   returning {"success":false}

I'm using **PHP** Version **7.1.25** on my local machine.

Comment: What is your apache and Mysql version?

Comment: Were do I see the apache and MySql version @Abhishek Panchal

Comment: Check out Aditya's answer. I was about to mention same thing that check Magento 2.3.x technology stack requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using PHP Version 7.1.25 on my local machine.

**[Magento 2.3.x technology stack requirements](http://Magento%202.3.x%20technology%20stack%20requirements)**

PHP 7.2 compatibility for the 2.3.0 release. Any backward-incompatibility issues will be resolved in this release, and all 3rd party libraries now support PHP 7.2. Fully tested 7.2 support will be delivered in following patch releases. If you are interested in participating in Magento Community projects we welcome your help! See our ZenHub board for a full list of outstanding issues.

[image]

**[For more reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)**